# Is targeting Kindle app on ipad possible with css media queries?

Tags: ipad, media-queries, epub, kindle, epub3

I am currently experiencing the nightmare that is called Kindle app for ipad. I am on ipad 1 Version 3.9.2

Kindle's support and documentation is abominable.

Here are my questions:

1)on the ipad 1, can you confirm that the app does NOT support KF8?

2)is there a media query which allows to target the kindle app for ipad and/or iphone. I had originally assumed that @media amzn-mobi would be sufficient. But I am finding that none of my media queries are working on the ipad app.

When I say "target", I mean that the media query will exclude the larger Kindle Fires and KF8 supporting androids  and instead allow css exclusively for the ipad kindle app.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The Kindle app on the iPad 1 is the same as the current Kindle app unless you have not allowed the app to update. The current Kindle for iOS app supports KF8. But you cannot just sideload a file. You need to use Kindle Previewer to create an AZK file. See the release notes for kindle previewer. Stuff has to go through iTunes and a sync. it's a pain, but the only way to make it go.
2. Media queries cannot target Kindle for iOS. You have 2 choices: KF8 or mobi. That's it. You cannot even target different kindle devices - for instance, you cannot target a Kindle Paperwhite from a Kindle Fire HDX - both support KF8, and that's the media query that will be used.

Comment: This is very interesting info and almost what I need. I will confirm this soon, but I want to mention that 1)I tried to test by emailing a mobi file to Personal Docs on my ipad app and 2)Amazon.com wrongly states that you can email an azw file via  Personal Docs to your kindle app on the ipad. http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200767340#GUID-6CE73410-8F68-4375-B482-7F327B8EF3C9 However, whenever I email an azw, file  Amazon.com will reply with a failure message.

Comment: Happily I can report that my syncing method was faulty, and that was producing the problems. If you synced the rendered azw file via itunes, that produced an accurate rendering (and it looks very close to kf8).